# Give classes to a child element of a v-html (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, css, string, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on a project to build my own CSS styleguide with Vue, and need to get a clean and with the fewest code as possible to enter each CSS elements.

Here is the component example which should later be the parent, so where we enter our example like in KSS or Documentcss.

```
<template>
    <div class="doc_container">

        <!-- Component Title -->
        <title-component>Button</title-component>

        <!-- Description Title -->
        <title-secondary>Button description</title-secondary>

        <!-- Description Text -->
        <description>

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Euismod nisi porta lorem mollis. Bibendum neque egestas congue
            quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus.

        </description>

        <!-- Creation of the example for the standard use
        :title = "'Title of your example'"
        :description ="'Description of your default example'"
         -->
        <default-example

        ></default-example>


        <!-- If you have several modifiers, repeat all the elements below with the last comment line -->
        <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------ -->


        <!-- Creation of the example(s) with the modifier(s)
        :title = "'Title of your example'"
        :description = "'Description of your example(s)'"
        :modifierClass = "'Change the first word to precise what kind of modifierClass this class is about'"
        :modifier = "'Refer to the correct object in your data so the loop can iterate through it and build your example'"
        -->

        <builder 
        :title="'Example'"
        :description="'Color Modifier.'"
        :modifierClass="'Color ModifierClass'"
        :modifier=this.modifiers1></builder>

        <!------------------------------------------------ End of Builder ------------------------------------------------->

        <!-- Creation of the example with the modifiers 
        :title: Title of your example
        :description: Description of your example
        :modifierClass: Change the first word to precise what kind of modifierClass this class is about
        :modifier: Refer to the correct object in your data so the loop can iterate through it and build your example
        -->

        <builder 
        :title="'Example'"
        :description="'Size Modifier.'"
        :modifierClass="'Size ModifierClass'"
        :modifier=this.modifiers2></builder>

        <!------------------------------------------------ End of Builder ------------------------------------------------->


    </div>
</template>

<script>
import addClass from '../../helpers.js'

import builder from '../doc/Builder.vue'
import defaultExample from '../doc/StaticBuilder.vue'
import titleComponent from '../doc/ComponentTitle.vue'
import titleSecondary from '../doc/SecondaryTitle.vue'
// import subTitle from '../doc/SubTitle.vue'
import description from '../doc/Description.vue'


export default {
    name: 'appButton3',
    components: {
        builder,
        defaultExample,
        titleComponent,
        titleSecondary,
        // subTitle,
        description,

    },
    data: function () {
       return {
           core: {
               /* Tag element used to create your examples */
               html:  `
                <button></button>
                `,

                /* Standard class if there is one */
                class: 'doc_button',

                /* HTML code that will be displayed and highlighted, so the user can see the code to use */
                example: `
                        <button class="doc_button ModifierClass">Default</button>
                        `,
            },
            /* Modifiers objects, copy and paste all the modifiers1 object if you need another one, and increment the number by one to have modifiers2.
               There is no limit to the number of modifiers objects you can have */
            modifiers1: {
                block1: {
                    /* Modifier Class */
                    class: 'doc_button--green',
                    /* Description of the usage of the class */
                    description: 'Primary Button'
                },
                block2: {
                    class: 'doc_button--orange',
                    description: 'Secondary Button'
                },
                block3: {
                    class: 'doc_button--red',
                    description: 'Tertiary Button'
                }
            },
            modifiers2: {
                block1: {
                    class: 'doc_button--small',
                    description: 'Small Button'
                },
                block2: {
                    class: 'doc_button--big',
                    description: 'Big Button'
                }
            }
        }
    },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">

    .doc_button {
        border-radius: 100%;
        width: 6rem;
        height: 6rem;
        background-color: #DDD;

        &--green {
            background-color: green;
        }

        &--orange {
            background-color: orange;
        }

        &--red {
            background-color: red;
        }

        &--small {
            width: 4rem;
            height: 4rem;
        }

        &--big {
            width: 8rem;
            height: 8rem;
        }
    }

</style>
```

Here is the builder, the component which automatically creates the example with your modifier classes:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="modifier">

            <h2 class="doc_title">
                {{title}}
            </h2>

            <p class="doc_description">
                {{description}}
            </p>

            <h3 class="doc_subtitle">
                {{modifierClass}}
            </h3>

            <ul class="doc_list doc_list--parameters" v-for="(block) in modifier" :key="block">
                <li class="doc_list-text"><p>{{block.class}}</p> : <p>{{block.description}}</p></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="doc_row">
                <div class="doc_list-container">
                    <ul class="doc_list" v-for="(block) in parentData.modifiers1" :key="block">

                        <div class="doc_list-element" 
                        v-html="parentData.core.html" 
                        :class="[parentData.core.class, `${block.class}`]">
                        </div>

                        <p class="doc_element-text"> {{block.class}} </p>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <pre class="doc_pre">
                <code class="language-html doc_code">   
                    <div v-text="parentData.core.html">
                    </div>
                </code>
            </pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: 'builder',
        props: {
            modifier: {
                type: Object
            },
            title: {
                type: String
            },
            description: {
                type: String
            },
            modifierClass: {
                type: String,
            }
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                parentData: this.$parent.$data
            }
        },
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

My problem is that the classes doc_button and the modifiers (doc_button--green,...) are added to the Div containing the button element added throught v-html.

But I need these classes to be directly added to the button element.
I precise that my styles are already not scoped.
Here is the code where I have the v-html and in which I want to add the classes to the child which are :

```
<div class="doc_list-element" 
                        v-html="parentData.core.html" 
                        :class="[parentData.core.class, `${block.class}`]">
                        </div>
```

```
data: function () {
       return {
           core: {
               /* Tag element used to create your examples */
               html:  `
                <button></button>
```

Should I add use vanillaJS to add the classes, and put that function in mounted?

```
document.getElementsByClassName('doc_button').childNodes.getElement.classList.add('doc_button')
```

It didn't work when I tried putting it in mounted hook.

Thanks for your help.